# How to hightlight rows in Excel 2013 that contains duplicate values?

Tags: excel

Have multiple columns in my sheet and two columns can have the same value. If two columns has the same value, I want to hightlight the row.

How can I achieve this for my complete worksheet?

Example:

```
A  |  B  |  C
1     2     3
2     4     4   // highlight this row
3     7     7   // highlight this row
4     5     5   // highlight this row
5     5     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting for this.

1. Select the area to be conditionally formatted with A1 being the active cell.
2. Go to the conditional formatting and pick "Use formula to determine which cells to format".
3. In the entry area, put the formula:

   ```
   =COUNTIF(1:1,A1)>1
   ```
4. Pick the formatting (Fill in your case) and click OK.

Change the active cell and corresponding reference in the formula as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how this works? I've looked for the COUNTIF() definition, but don't understand why this works..

Comment: @Martijn `COUNTIF` takes 2 parameters, first a range and second a criteria. It will count the number of occurrences of the criteria in the range. When you select everything and the active cell is A1, the formatting condition on A1 will be `=COUNTIF(1:1,A1)>1`. The one in B1 will be `=COUNTIF(1:1,B1)>1`. The one in A2 will be `=COUNTIF(2:2,A2)>1`. All to say that when you don't freeze the references, the conditional formatting 'adjusts' itself automatically for the condition and `1:1` refers to the whole row. In the end, excel is checking each cell, in every row. I hope that makes some sense ^^